# How do I change the foreground text color of (local variable '...' is never used) in code

Tags: c#, coderush

I can't find a way to change that anywhere and CodeRush sets the foreground color to a very light gray that is nearly unreadable on my monitor's white background. It is hard to read the code when variable names (as well as unused method parameters and using directives) are this light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options, such as colors of the different code issue types underlining, are available inside the Visual Studio configuration dialog. From the main IDE window, go to Tools | Options…, then Environment | Fonts and Colors. In the “Display items:” list, you can find the Dead Code item. For this item, you can  change the “Item foreground” and “Item background” color properties.

See more details here: [CodeRush Code Issues configuration and options](http://www.skorkin.com/2011/05/code-issues-configuration-and-options/)

Comment: ```Dead Code under Tools / Options -> Environment / Fonts and Colors``` is what I was looking for. The problem is that CodeRush then takes the foreground item color I select and lightens it, making for example black into gray.